# OpenWRT: TL-MR3020 Cannot SSH or TELNET into router flashed with custom OpenWRT bin

Tags: wifi, openwrt, router

I have a [TL-MR3020](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-mr3020) that I flashed with a custom binary built from OpenWRT source.

I was trying to enable WiFi and connect to the internet on the router by editing `/etc/config/network` and `/etc/config/wireless`. I changed the IP type from 'static' to 'dhcp' for LAN. I changed 'disable' to 0 for WiFi, set the SSID, encryption to 'psk' and a valid key.

These changes I made through SSH while being connected by a LAN wire. I disconnected LAN, then tried connecting to the WiFi created and successfully did too.

After that I can't SSH/TELNET into the router to do anything else. I cannot even reset it.

Any solution for this? either a way to SSH/TELNET to access the settings, or a way to reset the settings entirely?

Edit: SSH or TELNET to 192.168.1.1 shows 'no route to host'

Comment: You can try to recover it in failsafe mode. https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/generic.failsafe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axQvgqvlhcU

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I succeeded in getting the flashing light of FailSafe mode but cant connect via telnet. Keep getting 'connection refused'

Comment: the doc link talks about using ssh as root in some releases.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro thanks for the help! I could successfully SSH into it and reset!

Comment: No worries. I also have an Archer v7 at home with openwrt, I have synthesized an answer for the benefits of others and for the points, trying to reach 3k

Comment: sorry archer c7 v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure to recover an openwrt you have lost control is to try the recover mode, as it will boot will a minimal configuration, a known IP, and depending on the version of open-wrt can be accessed via telnet or ssh.

You have here the links to the considerations of the procedure https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/generic.failsafe and a youtube video talking about it at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axQvgqvlhcU

Basically you reboot it, and when one of the leds is blinking in a particular pattern you press the reset or the power off button. The appliance will then boot in safe mode with the default IP address 192.168.1.1.

As we have seen in your case, it will then be enough to ssh to it as root with no password.

As for people thinking what is openWrt, it is a Linux-based open source substitute firmware for the standard image that comes with some models of routers that happen to have hardware compatible with Linux and that in some cases have placed their firmware or parts of their firmware in the domain of open source.

The firmware gives you more control, and often will also provide extra functionality. In my case, the default firmware does not allow the use of the VLAN chipset for more than the standard Internal/external network at fixed ports, whilst with openWRT the VLANs can be programmed at will, and extra functionality can be added with standard Linux software.

I will leave here a link about the differences between openWRT, dd-wrt and Tomato.

https://www.quora.com/Which-is-best-for-WiFi-routers-Tomato-DD-WRT-OpenWRT-or-something-else

Comment: In my particular case, I use another address at home and I have also changed the default boot to be that address just in case. I might play with VLANs in a very near future and they do not exactly match one by one directly to the web interface and there is an high change I might lost control of it. I already have a WAN VLAN and a VoIP VLAN at home...Thanks for the points.

Answer (score 0):

tp 3020 travel routers have a three option sliding switch on the side of the router. Make sure you have it set on the right setting, otherwise you won't be able to access it, even if the ports show 'open' on a port scan. Just switch the slider, reboot the router (unplug and plug back in), and try logging in again. If that doesn't work, you can always pop the top of and access it over UART, the command to reset it is something like 'set to firstboot' or something similar, just google.